# Encoding two different languages using pd.read_csv problem

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nlp, machine-translation

I am building a Neural Machine Automatic Translator from German to Arabic. I am reading a CSV file containing German sentences and their corresponding Arabic translations. I want to read both languages at the same time using `pd.read_csv`. I have tried all the codes for all languages in this [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) but none of them worked.

[image: Aliases encoding for all languages]

The only thing that worked best for me is this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("DLATS.csv", encoding ='windows-1256')
```

'windows-1256' is the encoding Alias for the Arabic language. But the problem is that it doesn't catch the German special characters like (ä) but it converts them into question marks (?). So the word drängte became dr?ngte.

So, can anyone please help me to solve this problem or how to work around it? I have thought of separating the German and Arabic sentences in separate CSV files so that each CSV file contains one row only, and then maybe I will try to mix them in the Python code. But it seems that `pd.read_csv` requires at least two columns in the CSV file to work.

Update: I have noticed that the original csv file contains these problems as well for the German language. So, I have finally managed to solve my problem by reading excel directly instead of csv since the original file is in Excel, so I used pd.read_excel without any encoding attribute and it worked well. I didn't know before that pandas has pd.read_excel.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use clear `read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('download.csv')
print(df)

   german      arabic
0  drängte     حث
```

If you get bad results it is possible that data is not properly saved in csv.

Comment: I tried clear read_csv but it didn't solve my problem. What happens when I use this is I get this error: '

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1: invalid start byte'

I am using Google Colab

Comment: @Bahgat post link to you csv data

Comment: I have noticed that the original csv file contains these problems as well for the German language. But how to convert excel to csv containing German and Arabic? I have tried many ways but non worked.

Comment: @Bahgat like i have said post link or data sample, without you don't receive support.

Comment: I have finally managed to solve my problem. The original file is in Excel, so I used pd.read_excel without any encoding attribute and it worked. I didn't know that pandas has pd.read_excel.